# Python 3.7.4 no module "_pywraplp" from ORTOOLS

Tags: windows-10, python, 64-bit

I am working with a Python program that I wrote some time ago, which uses the `ortools pywraplp` solver. When I execute the program I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\win10\PycharmProjects\Sabt\FeederMapping\venv\lib\site-packages\ortools\linear_solver\pywraplp.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ortools.linear_solver._pywraplp' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

I have read that this could be due to the python 32-bit version. I have installed the 64-bit version and uninstalled the 32-bit one, but it keeps giving the same error.

I am working on Windows 10 Home (86x 64-bit), Intel core i7-6500 and running Pycharm Community Edition 2019, where I select a virtual python interpreter for my project. This enables me to have the needed libraries, including `py3-ortools` while using the local interpreter located at `C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`. When I execute this .exe I get:

> Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC
>   v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
>   "license" for more information.

How can I solve this problem with the module `pywraplp`? It is getting annoying since I have worked quite a lot with this solver and environment.

Comment: Just to cover all the bases, have you confirmed that `pywraplp` is actually installed in `C:\Users\win10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`?

Comment: You were pointing out to the right question. I´ve checked on both virtual and original interpreters and I was lacking the normal "ortools" library. I had just installed the py3-ortools. It seems both are needed in the virtual interpreter. Now it is working again. Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad you got it solved. =)